# Can I integrate an exiting blog platform into my website

Tags: seo, blog, content

I had asked this question on [Software Recommendation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/78697/how-to-add-an-existing-blog-platform-into-my-website) but did not get any answer.

I am working on an e-commerce website, which is developed in ASP.NET MVC... I want to build a blog for the website and add some content to the blog to improve website's ranking in the Search result.

I want my blog to be reached using: my-site.com/blog

Is it possible to integrate an existing blog platform such as [Medium](https://medium.com/) or [Blogger](http://www.blogger.com) into my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely technically doable but maybe not a great idea.

Doing this would require a reverse proxy to unify 2 different namespaces into one.  (You might be able to pull it off with mod_proxy for Apache for example).  This will cause undue delays and puts you at the mercy of changes by the blog provider. You may also run afoul of the remote provider t&c's

You might want to consider blogging on your own platform and syndicating your content to other providers or using a CMS that will allow you to integrate with them using an API (assuming they offer one)

Have you looked at running Wordpress for you blog? Its pretty good at that and is widely supported. Another thought is to consider putting your nlog on blog.example.com so that this can be on seperate infrastructure to your main website.

Comment: Thanks for this... I had looked at www.dnnsoftware.com as a CMS... Will checkout wordpress... using a subdomain was another question that I asked earlier today... not sure which is better but so far I am leaning towards using a subdirectory instead of subdomain...

Comment: For SEO, a subdirectory is better.  For everything else related to a CMS a subdomain is the way to go